# How to create mappers for classes from multiple packages using mirah?

Tags: codenameone

I use the DataMapper.mirah file to generate mapper classes. On the top of the DataMapper.mirah file you need to specify the package and only classes from that packages can be used.

How do I generate mappers for classes from multiple packages in my project?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to achieve this.

1. Create multiple DataMapper files in the corresponding packages.  E.g. com/example/utils/DataMapper.mirah (which would include your datamappers in the com.example.utils package), and com/example/ui/DataMapper.mirah which would include your mappers for the com.example.ui package.  Etc...
2. Mirah files can include multiple packages, so you could create just a single DataMapper file, and include all of the packages.

E.g.

```
package com.example
data_mapper MyClass:MyClassMapper
data_mapper SomeOtherClass:SomeOtherClassMapper  

package com.example.util
data_mapper MyUtilClass:MyUtilMapper

etc..
```